What's the easiest way to remove Hardie board that's been shot down to cement flooring with a Hilti gun or the hilty gun
In a garage they shot down the Hardy board with the Hilton gun directly to the cement and now the new owners wanted up so they can repair the garage floor.

A big spud bar.  Or can try try an excavator/backhoe or a few sticks of TNT.  It is coming up in pieces either way.

Yep, there is no easy way to do this, It's grunt work no matter what.

Have a "take out your frustrations on my floor" party with prybars and sledgehammers for all the guests.

You might try an angle grinder for the concrete nails… only bad thing is that you’ll inevitably scuff the concrete if you cut them low enough.

Get a lever or two under it and break off the cement board. use an angle grinder to cut off the nails (they're not coming out)
